# skip on more then one specific folders in FOR loop

Tags: batch-file, cmd

With some help I eventually managed to find a FOR loop that search the computer for a file that have the same name as the input string. Now my only problem is that I want the for loop to skip two directories instead of just one. Is it even possible?

```
for %%a in (C D E F G H U W) do (
    for /f "tokens=*" %%b in ('dir /s /b "%%a:\%filename%" ^|findstr /v /i /L /c:"%cd%\directory i want to skip" ') do (
    ---
    ---
    ---
    )
)
```

I tried this way but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
for %%a in (C D E F G H U W) do (
    for /f "tokens=*" %%b in ('dir /s /b "%%a:\%filename%" ^|findstr /v /i /L /c:"%cd%\directory i want to skip" ^|findstr /v /i /L /c:"%cd%\ another directory i want to skip" ') do (
    ---
    ---
    ---
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using `/c:"string"` twice in the same `findstr` statement:

```
 for /f "tokens=*" %%b in ('dir /s /b "%%a:\%filename%" ^|findstr /v /i /L /c:"%cd%\directory /c:"%cd%\ another directory i want to skip" ') do (.....
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. You can double-up on the `c:"..."` clause in the `findstr` or you could construct a file of all of your required exclusions and use this file as a `/g:filename`, as I advised you in your last question.